# Reduce the gap between \begin{theorem} and [name]

Tags: spacing, theorems

How can we reduce the gap between the number of a theorem and the name of it, for example
if we use

```
\begin{theorem}[Zorn's Lemma]
```

we have **Theorem 0.1** (Zorn's Lemma).

But my goal is to reduce the distance between **0.1** and (Zorn's Lemma).

**Theorem 0.1**(Zorn's Lemma).

**EDIT: Add MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks, plainpages]{hyperref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Zorn's Lemma]
If $X$ is a partially ordered set and every linearly ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element.
\end{theorem}

\vspace{20}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Theorem 0.1}(Zorn's Lemma).
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why? This doesn't look good.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that demonstrate your default behaviour. So we are able to see which package influences the style.

Comment: Also, specify which `theorem` environment you are using.  The built-in one, package `theorem`, some AMS package, or something else?

Comment: @Alex: My supervisor emphasizes that this gap should not exist and asked me to remove it in my dissertation, to allow me to graduation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: see [this](http://uploadboy.com/76ugdmib9vm4.html).

Comment: @Empty.Subset: It's always the best to include code inside your question instead of linking any other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your work with the documentclass `amsart` you don't need to load the packages `amsmath` or `amsthm`. The documentation provided the following information at page 2:

> **Packages.** The AMS document classes incorporate the code for the AMS theorem (`amsthm`) package and automatically load the `amsmath`
>   package. It is not necessary to request either one explicitly. The
>   user guides for these packages [ATP, AMP] contain the details, which
>   will not be repeated here. The `amsfonts` package is loaded as well,
>   unless the `[noamsfonts]` option is specified; see the AMSFonts User’s
>   Guide [AFG] for the features provided.

You request can be solved by redefining the command `\thmhead` where the space is hard coded.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
%  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}%original
  \thmnote{{\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}%new
\makeatother
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{{\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Zorn's Lemma]
If $X$ is a partially ordered set and every linearly ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element.
\end{theorem}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Theorem 0.1}(Zorn's Lemma).
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However without the space it looks weird.